# Who nominates EU commissioners?

Tags: european-union

If I understand correctly, the EU Commission is voted for by the 28 heads of the constituent governments of the EU.

Who nominates the candidates for the heads of state to vote on, and what is the voting mechanism (qualified majority?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you did not understand correctly.

Only the President of the European Commission is appointed by the European Council (the council of heads of state).

All of this is described in [Article 17 of the Treaty of the European Union](http://www.lisbon-treaty.org/wcm/the-lisbon-treaty/treaty-on-european-union-and-comments/title-3-provisions-on-the-institutions/86-article-17.html). The [Wikipedia article on the President of the European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_the_European_Commission) also provides background how the process evolved over the history of the European Union.

The election of the President of the European Commission works as follows:

1. The European Parliament (the parties elected by EU citizens directly) nominates candidates. While not strictly codified in European law, it is common practice that each party group of the parliament nominates one person (this process is just described with the sentence *"Taking into account the elections to the European Parliament and after having held the appropriate consultations"* in 17.7. The practice of party group appointment grew historically).
2. The European Council (heads of governments of EU states) picks among those proposed by the parliament. They have to agree on a candidate with qualified majority. They can *theoretically* also pick someone not proposed by the Parliament, but that's likely to fail, because...
3. The candidate must be approved by majority of the European parliament. When the parliament vetoes a candidate, the Council has to agree on someone else within a month.

After the President of the Commission is elected, each government (except the one where the President is from) appoints one commissioner. How they make that decision is up to each government. However, they would be well-advised to pick someone the President can work with, because the President can <strike>fire</strike> request the resignation of commissioners at will.

And finally, the whole commission must be approved again by a parliament majority. The parliament can not reject individual commission members; they need to accept either all of them or none. However, the threat of shooting down the whole commission because of a few unpopular members has in the past convinced individual governments to revise their appointment.