# Where are the nominees for the President of the European Commission sourced from?

Tags: european-union, president

From where are the nominees for the President of the European Commission sourced?

[This answer](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11094/who-nominates-eu-commissioners) says:

> "The European Parliament (the parties elected by EU citizens directly)
>   nominates candidates. While not strictly codified in European law, it
>   is common practice that each party group of the parliament nominates
>   one person (this process is just described with the sentence "Taking
>   into account the elections to the European Parliament and after having
>   held the appropriate consultations" in 17.7. The practice of party
>   group appointment grew historically)."

But where do the party groups look for their nominees? Their own members? Their friends? Elected officials somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who nominates EU commissioners?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11094/who-nominates-eu-commissioners)

Comment: that question does not answer the source of the presidential nominees.

Comment: Another way of stating this question would be "Who can be nominated as President of the European Commission?"  Note that for the President of the US, the answer would be "from among natural-born citizens who will be 35 by inauguration."  The answer in Europe could be similar or there may be no limit.  That isn't answered in the claimed duplicate.

Comment: I am not completely clear about what you want to know exactly but looking at past examples, it's typically an active or recently retired top-level politician (cabinet minister or head of government) from one of the smaller member states. Same thing of the president of the European council. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The EU election of 2019 is an interesting case study.

Prior to the election, the European parties nominated their leading candidates:

- The EPP nominated its chair and MEP, the German Weber.
- The S&D nominated the Dutchman Timmermans, who was serving as Commissioner and Vice-President of the Commission. At this point, he had not been a member of the European Parliament but had served in the Dutch government and had been elected to the Dutch parliament as a member of the Dutch Labour Party which is one of the parties that form the S&D.
- The RE (formerly ALDE) nominated Danish Vestager. She was also serving as Commissioner and had previously held government positions in Denmark. She too was elected to her national parliament as a member of the Danish Social-Liberal Party which is part of ALDE/RE.
- The Greens nominated the MEPs Eickhout (Netherlands) and Keller (Germany); both members of the local Green parties and sitting for the European Green Party.
- The ID nominated Italian MEP Zanni, again member of the ID's parliamentary group and, in Italy, the local Lega.
- The same can be said for the ECR's Zahradil, Czech MEP.
- (The candidates of the Left (GUE/NGL) were not elected to the European Parliament. I presume they too were local members of the respective parties.)

Given the outcome of the election, Weber was initially expected to become President of the Commission.

The heads of state negotiated for quite a while and ultimately presented Ursula von der Leyen, who had no prior position in European politics but who was a member of the German government and German parliament for the CDU, whose MEPs are part of the EPP.

So in a sense one could say that the parties sourced the nominees for president from their members who had some sort of prior experience at the European level (usually MEPs, sometimes Commissioners), while the candidate that was ultimately chosen only had the virtue of belonging to one of the parties that makes up the group that won the EP elections.

Which means that effectively the pool from which to nominate is 'all active politicians in one's party family'.